# Is Logical Min-Cut Problem, NP-Complete?

Tags: np, graph-theory, algorithms

**Logical Min Cut (LMC) Problem:** Suppose that G = (V, E) is an unweighted digraph, s,t are two vertices of V, and t is reachable from s. LMC Problem states that how we can make t unreachable from s by the removal of some edges of G but following two constraints: (1) the number of the removed edges must be minimal and (2) we cannot remove every exit edges of any vertex of G. We call logical removal the second constraint. So we look for *logical minimal* removal of some edges of G such that t would be unreachable from s.

**Comments**
**1-** If we ignore the logical removal constraint of LMC problem, it will be min-cut problem in the unweighted digraph G so it will be solvable polynomially (max-flow min-cut theorem). Furthermore, If we ignore the minimal removal constraint of LMC problem, it will be again solvable polynomially because it is sufficient to find the vertex k such that k is reachable from s and t is not reachable from k. Then consider the path p which is an arbitrary path from s to k. Now consider the path p as a subgraph of G. The answer will be every exit edges of the subgraph p. It is obvious that the vertex k can be found by some DFS in G in polynomial time. Hence,  **by considering just one of the constraints of LMC problem, it will be solvable polynomially.**

 
**2-** I tried to solve LMC problem by dynamic programming technique but the number of the required states for solving the problem became exponential. Moreover, I tried to reduce some NP-Complete problems such as 3-SAT, max2Sat, max-cut, and clique to LMC problem but I had some problems in reduction.Finally, I personally think that LMC problem is NP-Complete even if G is a binary DAG. 

**Question(s):**
1) Is LMC problem NP-Complete in an arbitrary digraph G? (main question)
 
2) Is LMC problem NP-Complete in an arbitrary DAG G?
 
3) Is LMC problem NP-Complete in an arbitrary binary DAG G?

Comment: I took the liberty to add a couple of relevant tags; hope that is ok.  Please retag as necessary.

Also, it is clear that it is not always possible to make $s$ and $t$ separable --- for example, take a line graph.

Comment: Let me clarify the constraint#2 of the LMC problem. If we ignore the constraint#2, it will be possible to make _t_ unreachable from _s_ by the removal of every exit edges of some vertices of _G_ such as _s_. In min-cut problem, this may happen but in our problem, you're not allowed to do this. As an illustrating example, consider the digraph _G_ with the vertices _v1,v2,v3,v4_ and the edges _(v1,v2),(v2,v3),(v2,v4)_. If we want to make _v4_ unreachable from _v1_, you cannot remove the edge _(v1,v2)_ but you can remove the edge _(v2,v4)_ because the edge _(v2,v4)_ has a sibling edge (_(v2,v3)_)

Comment: In special cases, it is not possible to make _t_ unreachable from _s_ regarding the constraint#2 (logical removal). By a simple observation, we can see that: **LMC problem has answer iff there exists a vertex _k_ such that _k_ is reachable from _s_ and _t_ is not reachable from _k_ which is determinable polynomially by some DFS.** Generally, ignore such special cases and consider general case of the problem. Moreover, I didn't have permission to define new tags such as 'min-cut' , 'edge-removal', 'logical', etc. Thanks for adding the tags.

Comment: I am also looking for a good estimation algorithm to solve the LMC problem. As it was told in the comment section of the problem definition, we can solve the problem by finding a path $p$ from $s$ to the vertex $k$ s.t. $k$ is reachable from $s$ and $t$ is not reachable from $k$. So the outgoing edges of the path $p$ (consider $p$ as a subgraph of $G$) will be an answer of the problem because the removal of the outgoing edges of p will make t unreachable from s and it is logical. This solution uses more edges. The answer of a good estimation algorithm should contain as less edges as possible. 

Comment: Crosspost: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1531/is-logical-min-cut-np-complete

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it received an answer at cs.se, where it had been cross-posted. Apparently the question belongs there.

Comment: Dear Todd, the received answer is not correct.
I finally managed to prove that this problem is NP-Complete.